# Action bar with custom background not shown

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the background of the action bar via xml, but the action bar is not shown anymore at all.

This is the style that I am using, declared in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/DiaryActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/DiaryActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="DiaryActionBar"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

I have set both `android:background` and `background` for compatibility. This is the only `styles.xml` file in my app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: widget.AppCompat is needed in the diaryActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my style with custom actionbar background, i have this:

```
<style name="Theme.Malaka" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<style name="Malaka.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

And that works just fine. Items of the styles are the same as yours. Please note that the parent of `Malaka.ActionBar` is not  `Theme...` but `Widget...`

Answer (score 0):

For changing background and actionBarStyle from android styling.You can do like this..

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DiaryActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_bg</item>
    </style>
```